# Azure Mobile App Service Authentication

Tags: authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Using above service with Xamarin form, I have enable authentication with OAuth (Microsoft and Google). API call are working fine and those functions with *[Authorize]*, are being enforced with authentication.

However, we're using server side authentication, hence after received the user token from respective provider, we check in our database if the user account is in there. If not there, we call another API function, to insert this account in the database and give user demo access to our app.

Hence, I should't have any authentication on this function. How to secure the function, to allow such user creation only from the app and not directly from the API site?

(I'm thinking of using a hardcoded key, and pass it parameter to the function if not other secure method is available)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I covered this in my blog.  See https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/13/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-20-custom-api/ for the first day, and then Day 21/22 as well.